# Euler Characteristic of Octagonal Closed Surface

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Let $X$ be a non-empty, closed octagonal surface, in which $3$ octagons meet at every vertex. I have to show that its Euler Characteristic is $χ(X)=-V/8$.

I have solved a similar exercise stating the following:

Let $Y$ be a triangular closed surface such that $m$ triangles meet at every vertex. Find its Euler Characteristic.

In order to find it I did the following $3F=2E=mV$ and thus showed that $χ(Y)=F(3/m-1/2)$

If I am to follow the same methodology for its solution i would have something along the lines of $kF=lE=3V$.

So my question is, what are the coefficients $k,l$ of $F,E$ going to be?

Comment: Notation: $()=−+$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint.* Every octagon has eight vertices, and three octagons meet at every vertex, from which you get a relation between $F$ and $V$. Every octagon has eight edges, and two octagons meet at one edge, from which you get a relation between $F$ and $E$. This means you can express $E,F$ in terms of $V$, and you are done. In order to find the relations exactly, just think about how to count the vertices/edges correctly.

Maybe illustrating the logic for your triangle example would help. The reason that $3F=2E$, as you wrote, is because every triangle (of which there are $F$) corresponds to three edges, while every edge corresponds to two triangles. So the number of $(\text{triangle},\text{edge})$ pairs can be counted as either $3F$ or as $2E$, so they are equal. Can you extend this logic to solve your new problem?

Comment: Thank you! I got $F=3V/8$ and $E=3V/2$ and thus shown that $χ(X)=-V/8$. Also, if I have to prove that $χ(Χ)<-2$, would it suffice to say that by default the surface has $V>16$?

Comment: @Toniiiic Well, you'd have to prove that. It's clear that $V = 8$ can't work, because the surface is made up of octagons and well, an octagon already has $8$ vertices. Now you'd have to come up with an argument to show $V=16$ can't work either.

Comment: that's the secondary explanation which I am considering stating. Since by definition we have 3 octagons meeting at each vertex we have, well, at least three octagons, which by definition have more than 16 vertices together already (tried some different methods of tiling and depending on the orientation I get either 20 or 19 vertices for 3 octagons).

Comment: @Toniiiic Yep, that sounds good to me!